# How to apply stateful computation to a list?

Tags: haskell, state-monad

Let's imagine a dummy subset of Brainf*ck:

`+` increments the counter

`-` decrements the counter

A simple program:

`program = "++++--" -- should evaluate to 2`

And a stateful evaluation function:

```
eval :: Char -> State Int Char
eval '+' = do x <- get
              put (x + 1)
              return 'I'
eval '-' = do x <- get
              put (x - 1)
              return 'D'
```

How would you evaluate the program?
(Looks like a `fold` to me but can't get my head around it, and it doesn't feel like it's the way to do it properly...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `traverse_` from `Data.Foldable`:

```
import Data.Foldable (traverse_)
execState (traverse_ eval "++++--") 0
```

Comment: works fine ! thanks ! Still have to get my head around many of the concepts.

Answer (score 5):

The function you are looking for is `sequence`, which has the signature `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`, and is a very common pattern when dealing with monads like `State`.

For your code, you would expect the evaluator to look like this:

```
evalBF :: String -> State Int String
evalBF = sequence . map eval
```

Which you would then fully evaluate with something like:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
       src <- getLine
       print $ runState (evalBF src) 0
```

Comment: `sequence . map f` is the same as `traverse f`, but the later has a more general type.

Answer (score 1):

An ugly solution but using the fold that you correctly suspected was applicable.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

program = "++++--"

eval :: Char -> State Int Char
eval '+' = do
    x <- get
    put (x + 1)
    return 'I'
eval '-' = do
    x <- get
    put (x - 1)
    return 'D'

evalList :: [Char] -> State Int Char
evalList = foldl (\s c -> (s >> eval c)) (return ' ')

main = putStrLn $ show $ runState (evalList program) 0
```